# PSTools and VB.net: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: vb.net, cmd

Im trying to write a program, for work, that will be able to tell me if one person is logged into more than one PC.

Im using PStool's PSloggedon cmd.

here is the code Im experimenting with:

> Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Proc.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("psLoggedon")
    'right now the textbox will hold a PC ID from a list of PC's in a database.
    Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l \\" & TextBox1.Text & ""
    Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Proc.Start()



    MsgBox(Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)



    Proc.Close()



End Sub
```

but I am getting this eror:

Win32Exception was unhandled:
The system cannot find the file specified

I checked here:
C:\Windows\System32

and made sure the application files were copied there and they were.

can someone help me out and explain to me what I can do to resolve this issue?

p.s. Im using windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "\\sysnative";
```

[32 bit system command](http://scottiestech.info/2009/06/20/calling-a-32-bit-system-command-from-a-script-in-x64-windows/)

Comment: where and how would I use this statement?

Comment: before Proc.StartInfo

Comment: actually the article you posted helped out. All I did was copy PStools application files in \windows\syswow64

thanks!